# Process.Start() in C# does not work for non-admin users

Tags: c#, privileges, system.diagnostics, administrator

I am trying to run explorer.exe to open a folder and I am using System.Diagnostics.Process to do that.

It works fine if the application is ran by a user who has admin privileges but fails if the user is not an admin.

I have tried:
 - running it by supplying a ProcessStartInfo.
 - Getting the explorer.exe process from the local machine and running it using that.
 - Running it on IExplore.exe.

Nothing of the above worked for non-admin users. ProcessStartInfo lets you prompt for admin credentials but that's undesirable because many users are not admins..

I know I can make this work by using some native methods (I've tried it), SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems, but I don't really want to use native code..

Comment: Post the code you are using, in the ProcessStartInfo...

Comment: "does not work"/"fails" - could you elaborate? - do you get an error message? Does the process start and immediately exit?

Comment: var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "explorer.exe",
                Arguments = "C:\\"
            };

            Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: when I say 'does not work' or 'fails' I mean that the Windows Explorer does not show and no exceptions are thrown..